# Cloudfront CDN Font blocked by CORS policy blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using a nginx as my host and a Amazon Cloudfront as my cdn.

my header from my cdn has the Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to *

From my site:

```
curl -I http://example.com/ThemeIcons.woff?387osh
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 03:01:23 GMT
Content-Type: application/font-woff
Content-Length: 18068
Last-Modified: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 05:35:17 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "55b32015-4694"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

From my cdn site:

```
curl -I http://cdn.example.com/ThemeIcons.woff?387osh
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/font-woff
Content-Length: 18068
Connection: keep-alive
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 03:01:35 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 25 Jul 2015 05:35:17 GMT
ETag: "55b32015-4694"
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=315360000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 251651f117f01cad42a0ea283b85cb0a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: iFxwbrqD8DWkxlnqsvFMHnO6M4BLU5bywk5MsicXZ00whNzV32U_Rw==
```

but still the message in chrome console showed,

```
Access to Font at
'http://cdn.example.com/ThemeIcons.woff?387osh' 
from origin 'http://cdn.example.com' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have researched this for 2 days, is there anyone can help me out ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you figure it out yet? A link to your cdn or the website that was to use the cdn would be helpful.

It could be that Chrome does a preflight OPTIONS request to your distribution, and that your origin doesn't have the header set for that. You can check this with 
`curl -I -X OPTIONS http://cdn.example.com/ThemeIcons.woff?387osh`